# How can the effectiveness chart be used for dual type pokémons?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've found a type effectiveness chart which lists all the move types (Water, Fire, Earth etc) against all the pokémon types at [http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/04/pokemon-go-types.htm](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/04/pokemon-go-types.html).  But I haven't seen any explanation for how to use that information for dual type pokémons.

For example, Lapras is Water/Ice.  Fire moves are super effective against ice, but not very effective against water.  So how effective are Fire moves against Lapras?

Answer (score 1):

If you hit Lapras with a firetype move, they will take 1x damage. The 2x bonus from Ice being weak is nullified by the 0.5x times resistance by the water, so it balances out to do 1x damage.